# Creating CloudWatch rule with AWS CloudFormation not linking to role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a CloudWatch rule that triggers on a schedule and executes a state machine (Step Functions). I'm using CloudFormation to create this, and everything creates fine except for the association of the IAM role used by the rule, to the rule itself. Here is what I mean:

Notice under 'Use Existing Role' it's blank.

[image]

Here is the CF template portion that deals with the rule and its role.

```
"SFInvoke":{
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": {
                "Fn::Sub": "states.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com"
              }
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Policies": [
        {
          "PolicyName": "StepFunctionsInvoke",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                  "states:StartExecution"
                ],
                "Resource": { "Ref" : "StateMachine"}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "CloudWatchStateMachineSDCEventRule": {
    "Type":"AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
      "Description":"CloudWatch trigger for the InSite Static Data Consumer",
      "ScheduleExpression": "rate(5 minutes)",
      "State":"ENABLED",
      "Targets":[{
        "Arn":{ "Ref" : "StateMachine"},
        "Id":"StateMachineTargetId",
        "RoleArn":{
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "SFInvoke",
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      }]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `SFInvoke` role to show up on the `Use existing role selector`?

If that is the case, you need to set the Principal to `events` instead of `states`.

You're editing the event target in the screenshot above, not the step function. Principal defines the service that can assume the role, in your case that is the events service.

Try this for role creation:

```
"SFInvoke":{
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "StepFunctionsInvoke",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "states:StartExecution"
              ],
              "Resource": { "Ref" : "StateMachine"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tartaglia - will this mean that the role is linked to the rule as I require? So it will be able to execute using that role? That's what I'm after, I'm after having the CF template produce the link between the role and the CloudWatch event, so that it can execute as required and trigger the state machine.

Comment: Yes, this will trigger the state machine. You also need correctly setup role on the state machine (this one would have the `states` principal), and a role on lambda (this one would have the `lambda` principal).

Comment: Thank you changing `states` to `events` solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Yaml would be as:
Based on the Principal: as an Events Based Services and Actions: to start the execution of a StepFunctions State Machine.

```
AWSEventsInvokeStepFunctions:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:  
              Service: 
                - events.amazonaws.com                   
            Action: sts:AssumeRole     
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AWSEventsInvokeStepFunctions
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - states:StartExecution
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:*"
```

The Role which is now generic in nature can be applied to a CloudWatch Event Rule, gives Rule with the permissions to be able to start the Execution of a StepFunctions State Machine based on an Amazon S3 Event.

```
AmazonCloudWatchEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - 'AWS API Call via CloudTrail'
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
          eventName:           
            - PutObject            
          requestParameters:
            bucketName:
              - !Ref EventBucket
      Targets:
        - 
          RoleArn: !GetAtt AWSEventsInvokeStepFunctions.Arn
          Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stateMachine:MyStateMachine"        
          Id: !Sub "StepExecution"
```

You can probably check more on [Start the Execution of State Machine based on Amazon S3 Event](https://medium.com/@dheerajarora_6502/starting-a-state-machine-execution-in-response-to-amazon-s3-events-serverless-cloudformation-f065506a3113)